# Finding nth largest number among three numbers

Tags: algorithm

Given numbers k, a, b, c. How to find the kth largest number among a, b, and c without using if or any  array or loop. min or max functions are provided.

Comment: Why aren't we allowed to use `if` or an array or loop. Context would be helpful.

Comment: Most likely this is a puzzle from the interview (or homework)

Answer (score 3):

You need something like that C++ fragment. In other languages it might look different.

```
auto 1st = max(a,max(b,c));
auto 3rd = min(a,min(b,c));
auto 2nd = a+b+c-1st-3rd;
return (2-k)*(3-k)*1st/2 + (k-1)*(3-k)*2nd + (k-1)*(k-2)*3rd/2;
```

It is assumed that k equals one of the numbers 1, 2, 3.

Incorporating 2 comments results in the more beautiful:

```
#define maybe(x) x*(x!=n1&&x!=n3)
auto n1 = max(a,max(b,c));
auto n3 = min(a,min(b,c));
auto n2 = maybe(a)+maybe(b)+maybe(c);
return n1*(k==1) + n2*(k==2) + n3*(k==3);
```

Also, my 1st version ignored the fact that identifiers can't start with a digit.

In some languages, (k==1) cannot be used as an integer, or is not guaranteed to be 0 or 1. In these languages, the 1st version may work better.

Regarding the overflow: That depends on the type.

For integer types, a+b+c-n1-n3 may cause an overflow, but is still correct. That's why: The result of a+b+c-n1-n3 will be correct in the lower bits. For example, if we use 32 bit numbers, a, b and c will be 32-bit-numbers and the result will be correct in the lowest 32 bits. That is, the result will be exactly a or be or c. Thus it is correct. Given the fact that for float numbers ^ won't work and the question did not specify the type of the numbers, I go back from ^ to + and -.

For non-integer types, an overflow may introduce a rounding error. To avoid that, I now chose an implementation that does not use + or - at all except when adding 0.

Comment: Nice solution, but keep in mind that (for example) `a+b+c` could overflow.

Comment: `a^b^c^1st^3rd` avoids overflow, but there's also overflow problems in the `return` line. Perhaps `(!(k-1))*1st + (!(k-2))*2nd + (!(k-3))*3rd`

Comment: could you briefly explain your idea behind the return statement? Or how do you get this?

Comment: @tobeka evaluate by hand (2-k)*(3-k) for k=1, 2, 3 and you'll see how it works.

Comment: i understand how it works, but i would like to know what leads him to get this answer? Like any patterns or ideas we can find on how to solve these tricky questions.

Comment: tobeka, the last line of first answer was inspired by the way polynomials are expressed as products of linear factors to show the zero points. For example, x²+1 has the zero points 1 and -1, which is obvious if you write it as (x-1)(x+1). I looked for polynomials that are 0 for e.g.. x==2 and x==3. Anyway, !(k-1) is more elegant.

Comment: @Hans Klünder !(k-1) is beautiful. i tried work with it by bitwise operation, but it only works with two parameters.